# openURL:sourceApplication vs didFinishLaunchingWithOptions with UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey

Tags: push-notification, uiapplication, openurl

I understand `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` returns `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey` when launching my app from another application.

I also understand that `openURL:sourceApplication` returns a URL passed when calling my app from another application, doing so in both cases of launching the app and returning from background.

Since `openURL:sourceApplication` seems to always be called, it seems most logical to place all logic there - It seems strange that `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` would contain the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey` at all to begin with?

My question is:  In which method should I place the functionality of handling the URL?

What is the best practice?

Comment: where you even able to find the UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey when you called the custom url from safari?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/OpeningSupportedFileTypes.html) says you should add the functionality of handling to `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.